# Server 2008 IPv6 Connectivity issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, routing, ipv6

I am having issues with my IPv6 connectivity via Windows Server 2008.

External traceroute shows each hop along the path, including the servers gateway. It then times out, never reaching the host.

From the host, I am able to ping the same gateway, cannot reach anything past it.

I have tried setting static routes to some external IP's I own, resetting the routes, and every combination that I can think of without luck.

Right now, I cannot help but think the router is not forwarding ipv6 packets...but I have been assured by netops that it is functioning correctly. As I am not completely familiar with ipv6 and Windows, I am hoping there is something trivial that I am missing.

Any help is appreciated. I will update this question with any information requested.

```
Server->Gateway{2001:db8:1:6::1} - Ping OK
Internet->Gateway{2001:db8:1:6::1} - Ping OK

Server->Gateway{2001:db8:1:6::1}->Internet - Not OK
Internet->Gateway{2001:db8:1:6::1}->Server - Not OK


Server IP Address: 2001:db8:5678:7890:65c2:c257:37c3:40f7
```

**First 64 of all IP's changed. All ping/traces have been done exclusively with IPv6.

```
netsh interface ipv6>sh route

Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
-------  --------  ---  ------------------------  ---  ------------------------
No       Manual    256  ::/0                       11  fe80::20c:dbff:fef8:8900
No       Manual    256  ::1/128                     1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       Manual    8    2001:db8:1:6::/64         11  WAN
No       Manual    256  2001:db8:1:6:65c2:c257:37c3:40f7/128   11  WAN
No       Manual    8    2001:db8:1:8:240::/96     11  WAN
No       Manual    256  fe80::/64                  13  Local Area Connection 2
No       Manual    256  fe80::/64                  15  Local Area Connection 3
No       Manual    256  fe80::/64                  17  Local Area Connection 4
No       Manual    256  fe80::/64                  11  WAN
No       Manual    256  fe80::69c2:c957:37b3:90f7/128   11  WAN
No       Manual    256  fe80::9dbb:be36:50c4:2e71/128   15  Local Area Connection 3
No       Manual    256  fe80::c9f3:3379:14f0:e48/128   17  Local Area Connection 4
No       Manual    256  fe80::f061:419e:da95:3f30/128   13  Local Area Connection 2
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                    1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                   13  Local Area Connection 2
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                   15  Local Area Connection 3
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                   17  Local Area Connection 4
No       Manual    256  ff00::/8                   11  WAN
```

Comment: Do any other machines on the same VLAN have IPv6 connectivity? Are you absolutely certain that that Brocade router is behaving?

Comment: At this point you should beat them over the head with a copy of the routing table. Looks like it's almost certainly their problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing table looks reasonable (aside from a strange route to a /96 but that probably isn't causing you any issues).

At this point it's time to look at the Brocade router that's serving as your default gateway and make sure that it's behaving properly.

Comment: You have mentioned Brocade multiple times, can I ask how you got that information? J/C

Comment: [It's right there](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-24485) in your default gateway: `fe80::20c:dbff:fef8:8900`. Which means the router's MAC address is 00:0c:db:f8:89:00, [and the manufacturer is](http://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) Brocade. That's about all that can be determined, though. Who knows what the model is.